# Three.js: Set position based on world vector

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to update a mesh's position to a global coordinate. However, when i do so, the results are very inaccurate.

```
// converting global to local
local = mesh.worldToLocal(position.clone())

// converting back to verify it is accurate
globalpos = mesh.localToWorld(local.clone())

// taking a snapshot for comparision
orig = mesh.position.clone()

// should just need to add the local vector, 
// as it is local to the mesh position
mesh.position.add(local)

// printing for debug
console.log(position, globalpos, orig, local, mesh.position)
```

`position` and `globalpos` are always identical. So it seems that the math isn't losing that much precision, but mesh.position can be off by a considerable amount (I observed .3 difference in one case)

How is this supposed to be done?

using three r71